# Linked in v2.0 API - How to get vanityname or public profile url?

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

In v1.0, We can able to get public profile url using below api.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,public-profile-url,first-name,last-name,email-address)?format=json

but in v2.0, when i try to get r_basicprofile its gives me Erro 403 (You dont have get /me permission), However i can get id, first name, last name using r_liteprofile.

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

How can i get public-profile-url or vanityName?

Thanks!

Comment: In order for your applications to access LinkedIn member data and/or act on their behalf, they must be authenticated

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Comment: Thanks, but issue is when i authenticate through oauth2 and try to get basic profile i only able to receive id, firstname, lastname not other information like we get in v1 api.

Comment: @NiravPatel Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @SimplyComplexable No still haven't figured out. I received answer from linked in as,

We are currently only reviewing and provisioning access to the functionality listed there (e.g. Marketing Analytics), rather than any other type of LinkedIn API. No functionality outside those listed is currently provided via this application.

Comment: @NiravPatel have you got the solution?

Comment: @ParthPatel Not so far, i have submitted the app for partnership program many times they not allowing special permission to get public profile

Comment: @NiravPatel or anyone else, did y'all figure out how to get around the restriction from the liteprofile to get the LinkedIn URL? Or even a way to get access to basicprofile?

Comment: @Reza No can't get the Linkedin URL with liteprofile, and basicprofile they can't provide us access

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't get the `vanityName` easily in v2, unless you apply for partnership program (as what KPSingh suggested) but LinkedIn discourages you to apply the partnership if you only want to get the `vanityName`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api-v1-migration

> **Please do not apply to a partner program** like the Marketing Developer Platform if you are seeking access to member profile data that is not made available via the new “Lite Profile” permission. Access to partner programs is appropriate for **select use cases only**, and all other requests for access will be **rejected**.

Also, in v2 `r_basicprofile` was replaced with `r_liteprofile` permission.

Answer (score 0):

For using this URL in V2 you have to take permission from linkedin 
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,public-profile-url,first-name,last-name,email-address)?format=json

this is relater to r_basicprofile

apply for partnership program

Comment: Thanks! I had applied for partnership program, waiting since a week for their reply.

Comment: @KPSingh I'm unable to find the place where to apply for LinkedIn partnership program. Right now I ran into the following issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255927/linkedin-api-2-and-public-profile-url Is there a chance to get user public profile url?

Comment: Check these :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/apply-with-linkedin

Comment: Check this also : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: Regarding the downvote - It's probably because this answer is clearly only for v1. Even the URL used in the answer includes `/v1/`. **This is not a valid solution for v2.**