# LinkedIn API 2 and VanityName from r_basicprofile

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, user-profile

LinkedIn recently updated their API and now I unable to get public user profile url(by **VanityName**) during OAuth2 authentication phase. Looks like **r_basicprofile** is not available anymore.

Is there any chance to get this url and if so, could you please describe how?

According to the following LinkedIn documentation [Find Profile by VanityName API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-vanity-name-api?context=linkedin/compliance/context)

> The use of this API is restricted to those developers approved by
>   LinkedIn and subject to applicable data restrictions in their
>   agreements.

But there is no any information how to apply to this API. How to apply to this API and get the appropriate permissions for **r_basicprofile**?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to become a partner although I'am struggling with the same thing

https://fullfabric.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007056847-Setting-up-a-LinkedIn-application-and-Applying-to-become-a-LinkedIn-Partner

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Do you already have any success with it?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Comment: Also, the LinkedIn Partner Program url https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply mentioned in the provided article returns ```Page not found```